# Insert image in Folder Show null value in Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to insert an image on the client side. image URL inserted in the grid but when I click save button then image URL not pass to the controller and show result null value. But Image URL show in grid image column but not pass to the controller.

And Second Question: when I upload an image then only show Url of the image I want to display image view can you give me the idea how I display image in this code.

c#

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult mQuotationInsert(int Qt_ID, string EnteryDate, string Purpose, Quotation[] Quot, string AddNew)
        {
            string result = "Error! Order Is Not Complete!";
            try
            {
                objQuotation.QuotationInsert(Qt_ID, EnteryDate, Purpose, Quot, AddNew);
                ModelState.Clear();
                result = "Quotation Inserted Successfully!";
                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

Javascript

```
// Add Multiple Record
    $("#addToList").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($.trim($("#PartyName").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#txtfile").val()) == "") return;

        var Srno = document.getElementById("detailsTable").rows.length,
            PartyName = $("#PartyName").val(),
            image = $("#txtfile").val(),
            IsMature = $("#chkNIsMature").is(":checked"),
            detailsTableBody = $("#detailsTable tbody");
            var Qt = '<tr><td>' + Srno + '</td><td>' + PartyName + '</td><td>' + image + '</td><td>' + IsMature+ '</td><td> <a data-itemId="0" href="#" class="deleteItem">Remove</a></td></tr>';
            detailsTableBody.append(Qt);
            clearItem();
    });



  $("#saveQuotation").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var QuotationArr = [];
            QuotationArr.length = 0;

            $.each($("#detailsTable tbody tr"), function () {

                QuotationArr.push({
                    Srno: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
                    PartyName: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
                    image: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(),
                    IsMature: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html()
                });
            });

            var data = JSON.stringify({
                Qt_ID: parseInt($("#txtQtID").val()),
                EnteryDate: $("#txtNEnteryDate").val(),
                Purpose: $("#txtNPurpose").val(),
                Quot: QuotationArr,
                AddNew: $("#AddNew").val()
            });

            $.when(saveQuotation(data)).then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }).fail(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
```

HTML

```
 <!--Detail-->
                            <h5 style="margin-top:10px;color:#ff6347">Quotation Details</h5>
                            <hr />
                            <div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="col">

                                        <div class="md-form">
                                            <label for="lblPartyName">Party Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" id="PartyName" name="PartyName" placeholder="Party Name" class="form-control" ,Required=true />


                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">

                                        <form class="md-form">
                                            <label for="lblPartyName">Image File</label>
                                            <div class="file-field">
                                                <div class="btn btn-outline-success  btn-sm float-left">

                                                    <input type="file" id="txtfile" name="file">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="file-path-wrapper" hidden>
                                                    <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload your file">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <!-- IsMature-->
                                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsMature, new { @class = "custom-control-input", @id = "chkNIsMature" })

                                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="chkNIsMature">Mature</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-offset-4">
                                        <a id="addToList" class="btn btn-primary">Add To List</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <table id="detailsTable" class="table">
                                    <thead style="background-color:#007bff; color:white">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th style="width:2%">SrNo.</th>
                                            <th style="width:40%">Party Name</th>
                                            <th style="width:30%">Image</th>
                                            <th style="width:30%">Mature</th>
                                            <th style="width:10%"></th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```