# Save the contents of a base64-encoded image string into a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to save image path in the database. I am using string type image not save in folder but image name also saved in the database. I am using a string so `SaveAs()` doesn't compile.

Why I am using string? Because when I am using `public HttpPostedFileBase imagefile {get;set;}` it shows a null value in the controller.

Model

```
   public string imagePath { get;set; } // contains the name of the image
   public string imageFile { get;set; } // contains string bytes
```

C#

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(Quot[i].imageFile.Replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", ""));

Image img;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data, 0, data.Length);
ms.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
img = Image.FromStream(ms, true);


string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Quot[i].imagePath);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(Quot[i].imagePath);
fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + extension;
Quot[i].imagePath = "~/AppFiles/Images/" + fileName;
fileName = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/AppFiles/Images/"), fileName);
Quot[i].imageFile.SaveAs(fileName);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No. problem in the last line of code how to save in a folder. i am using string but SaveAs not working save as work only Httppostfilebase. in this scenario How to save .@Tasos K.

Comment: Is there a specific reason on why you load the file contents to an `Image`? If you don't wish to process the image, you could handle it as any other file.

Comment: Sir kindly tell me how to save the image in Folder SaveAs not working when I use string. How to resolve this issue. if this is done my problem resolved. @Tasos K

Comment: See the answer from @CodeCaster below.  Fix the actual problem, not the new one you've found when trying to ignore the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Why I am using string? Because when I am using `public HttpPostedFileBase imagefile {get;set;}` it shows a null value in the controller.

Then rather fix that problem, instead of converting your code to work with a base64 string.

See for example [HTTPPostedFileBase always return null in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218971/httppostedfilebase-always-return-null-in-controller).

Anyhow, if you want to save an image, of which `byte[] data` holds the bytes, then simply write those bytes to a file:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, data);
```

Comment: My problem is this line Quot[i].imageFile.SaveAs(fileName); SaveAs show error How to resolve this .@CodeCaster

Comment: and this my complete [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52756428/how-to-insert-image-on-client-side-using-jquery-ajax) you can see what is the problem in my code if i am using Httppostfilebase

Comment: See the link in my answer, your form is not OK.

Comment: when i replace this line show this error: : 'Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Office Project\New\InventoryManagementSystem\InventoryManagementSystem\AppFiles\Images\elementary16\10\2018.jpg'.'

Comment: can you tell me what is the problem in my from @CodeCaster

Comment: where I use this below the SaveAs File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, data); but getting error i have share the error @CodeCaster